# SQL Query - Insert Multiple rows with each row having inremental date (+7) other values same

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create an `INSERT` query so that all columns except 1 are the same but the one column that isn't is a date that increments by a week up to a selected date.

E.g.:

```
Row   UserID   Date           Out      In    Reason    Details
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1       12     2015-04-01      9       5     Other     Flexible Hours
2       12     2015-04-08      9       5     Other     Flexible Hours
3       12     2015-04-15      9       5     Other     Flexible Hours
4       12     2015-04-22      9       5     Other     Flexible Hours
5       12     2015-04-29      9       5     Other     Flexible Hours
6       12     2015-05-06      9       5     Other     Flexible Hours
7       12     2015-05-13      9       5     Other     Flexible Hours
8       12     2015-05-20      9       5     Other     Flexible Hours
```

So I was thinking something like

```
INSERT INTO Holidays(UserId, Date , Out, In, Reason, Details) 
VALUES ('12', (DATEADD(DAY, +7, GETDATE()), '9', '5', 'Other', 'Flexible Hours') ;
```

but as I'm fairly new to SQL, I have no idea if this would work and also I don't know how to repeat this until "date" = specific date.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a recursive `CTE`:

```
DECLARE @from DATE = '2015-04-01'
DECLARE @to DATE = '2015-05-20'

;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT @from AS [Date]

   UNION ALL

   SELECT DATEADD(d, 7, [Date]) AS [Date]
   FROM CTE
   WHERE DATEADD(d, 7, [Date]) <= @to
)
INSERT INTO Holidays(UserId, [Date] , [Out], [In], Reason, Details) 
SELECT '12', [Date], '9', '5', 'Other', 'Flexible Hours'
FROM CTE
```

The recursive `CTE` used above creates the following temporary result set:

```
Date
----------
2015-04-01
2015-04-08
2015-04-15
2015-04-22
2015-04-29
2015-05-06
2015-05-13
2015-05-20
```

This set of results is then inserted into `Holidays` table using an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eebce/1)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to generate such date series (and other values) based on row_number() and some table that is containing some rows. In this case I am using sys.all_objects.
I find that this method produces very fast clean and easily read code.

The row_number will generate a list of numbers from 1 and up. That number is then used to calculate the new date (7 * N) days + startDate.

```
DECLARE @fromDate DATE = '2015-04-01';
DECLARE @toDate DATE = '2015-05-20';

WITH dates AS (
  SELECT dateadd(day, 7 * rn, @fromDate) AS [Date] FROM
  (
    SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS rn 
    FROM sys.all_objects
  ) rns
)
INSERT INTO Holidays(UserId, [Date] , [Out], [In], Reason, Details) 
SELECT '12', [Date], '9', '5', 'Other', 'Flexible Hours'
FROM dates
WHERE [Date] < @toDate;
```

There are many ways of generating sequences, some discussed in detail in this nice series of articles: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1